Problem with changing a raster in Lambert Conformal Conical projection to unprojected using terra in R
I have a raster in Lambert Conformal Conical projection that I would like to change to unprojected.
I tried to use the project function in terra package.The result raster has an extent that is very off from the region where it should be.
Here is the CRS of the original raster in proj4 as recognized by QGIS:
"+proj=lcc +lat_0=90 +lon_0=100 +lat_1=0 +lat_2=57.29577951 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
Here are the codes that I tried so far, along w/ the metadata of the raster object (Thanks @L Tyrone for the suggestion : ) )
#The raster in Lambert projection. 
flood<-rast("flood_2014_Glenda.tif")
#dimensions  : 14983, 11835, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 19.99915, 19.99915  (x, y)
#extent      : 2482274, 2718964, 1287189, 1586836  (xmin, xmax, 
#ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP 
#min value   :                 0 
#max value   :                 1 

#An unpojected vector object. It is the same region as the raster 
#object.   
bicol<-vect("phl_adm2_bicol.shp")
#geometry    : polygons 
#dimensions  : 6, 14  (geometries, attributes)
#extent      : 122.2986, 124.4249, 11.72048, 14.50116  (xmin, xmax, 
#ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)


flood_unprojected<-project(flood,crs(bicol))
flood_unprojected
#dimensions  : 1966, 19090, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.0007564935, 0.0007564935  (x, y)
#extent      : -30.45265, -16.01119, 82.91273, 84.4  (xmin, xmax, 
#ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#name        : flood_2014_Glenda 
#min value   :               NaN 
#max value   :               NaN 

#Note that the extent of flood_unprojected is very different from 
#that of the vector.

@margusl, I tried your suggestion, and my workflow also did not work for the input raster created from the terra system file. Here are the codes :
r_lcc <- terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", 
package="terra")) 
|> terra::project("+proj=lcc +lat_0=90 +lon_0=100 +lat_1=0 
+lat_2=57.29577951 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
+type=crs")
bicol<-vect("phl_adm2_bicol.shp")

r_lcc_unproj<-project(r_lcc,crs(bicol))
r_lcc_unproj
#extent: 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, 
#ymin, 
#ymax)

r_lcc_o<-rast("C:/Users/xiaoj/AppData/Local/R/win- 
library/4.3/terra/ex/elev.tif")
r_lcc_o
#extent: 5.164309, 7.115402, 49.17813, 50.44312  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
#ymax)


It will be easier to help you if you provide the metadata of your raster object and the code you have tried so far. Add this information as an edit to your question.

Does your workflow fail in a similar way when you try to use something like r_lcc <- terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")) |> terra::project("+proj=lcc +lat_0=90 +lon_0=100 +lat_1=0 +lat_2=57.29577951 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs") as an input raster?

There's something wrong with the way flood_2014_Glenda.tif was created. For example, if you filter rnaturalearth::ne_countries() to just the Philippines and project it using your PROJ string, the extent is 1770265, 2749372, -11792450, -10571320 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax). However, your flood object extent is 2482274, 2718964, 1287189, 1586836 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax). In other words, your longitude values look OK, but your latitude values are wrong. Given there's some error, I don't think you can even trust those longitude values.

If you created flood_2014_Glenda.tif, go back and check each step you used to create it. If it was supplied to you or you downloaded it,  contact the person who supplied the data and get them to confirm whether there is an error or not. If you downloaded the data, add the direct download link to your question as an edit. Ensure the link does not require authentication or logging in. Good luck!

Alternatively, if your data are not located in the Philippines, there's something wrong with phl_adm2_bicol.shp.

@ L Tyrone, thank you so much! Yes, the raster file is supposed to be in the Philippines. I will contact the person who supplied the data.
